# Flutter Mockito. Failing to mock

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mockito, dio

I am trying to use `mockito` in my project to test an API. Here is a small snippet code under `organization_test.dart`. I will only provide up until the error line as it is the only concern.

```dart
class MockOrganizationRemoteDataSource extends Mock implements OrganizationRemoteDataSource {}


void main(){
 late final MockOrganizationRemoteDataSource mockOrganizationDataSource;
 late final IOrganizationRepository iOrganizationRepository;
 final tOrgName = "someOrgName";

 setUp((){
  mockOrganizationRemoteDataSource = MockOrganizationRemoteDataSource();
  iOrganizationRepository = IOrganizationRepository(mockOrganizationRemoteDataSource);
 });

 test("Should fetch the organization",() async {
  when(mockOrganizationRemoteDataSource.getOrganization(tOrgName)) // Getting ERROR on this line
   .thenAnswer(
      (_) async => Response(
       requestOption: RequestOption(
        path: <Some url in here >
        data: <Some json response here >
        responseType: ResponseType.json)
      ),
   );
 
   final result = await iOrganizationRepository.fetchOrganization(tOrgName);   
   
   ...
   ... // some more code here


 });
}
```

Then I get error is `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response<dynamic>>'`

I was expecting that if I use mock I can call the `getOrganization` method from the mockedDataSource and pretend to answer a response. Yet upon debugging this, I always ending up referencing to the Un-mocked class which is the `OrganizationRemoteDataSource` resulting the null value.

BTW I'm using flutter with null-safety enabled and `Dio`.

Comment: Did you follow the null-safety instructions and call `@GenerateMocks`?

Comment: Apparently, I have not and doesn't know that. Will check now. Thanks! I'll ask again if  I still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin! It worked using the @GenerateMocks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to jamesdlin's comment I was able to resolve this:

- Add `@GenerateMocks` annotation to the void main()

```dart
@GenerateMocks([OrganizationRemoveDataSource])
void main(){
...
}
```

- Removed the `MockOrganizationRemoteDataSource` class and used the build_runner to allow Mockito to generate the annotated GenerateMocks.

UPDATE:

Due to the intricacy of using `Mockito` in a null-safety dart. I came across a great library that works as alternative named `Mocktail`. You can see the library here https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail.